# Swift: Click onto cell of UICollectionView and open AlertViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, click

In my app, I am using an UICollectionView. Now I want to develop an UIAlertController, when clicking onto any cell of the collection view.
I started with following code:

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    …
}

// specify cells
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ….
}

// called when widget is moved
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        …
}

// called when clicked
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Got clicked!")
}

}
```

But somehow, "Got clicked!" is never printed.

Comment: Did you set the delegate and the data source?

Comment: No, how do I do that? Sorry, I am a beginner :D

Comment: @AlexanderJeitler-Stehr, It's great to know that you've started iOS and learning Swift. You just miss adding **UICollectionViewDelegate** to the extension. Just add it after **UICollectionViewDataSource** and you're good to go. Make sure you've bind the delegate to the `HomeViewController `. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try next:

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

}
```

or

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   ...
   cell.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(_:))))
}

func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   let location = sender.location(in: self.collectionView)
   let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location)

   if let index = indexPath {      
      print("Got clicked on index: \(index)!")
   }         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I will now use the second version. Could you please tell me how to pass the index of the tapped cell from the tap function to the

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell

?

Comment: You don't need do it. You add gesture recognizer in your each cell, and when you select one of cells, in method tap(_:) you obtain index. If you want change your selected cell, you can use this code to use this cell:  let cell = self.messageCollectionView.cellForItem(at: index)

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Comment: you just saved my ass! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the version using the delegate:

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("item at \(indexPath.section)/\(indexPath.item) tapped")
  }
}
```

Instead of using the extension you can also just add UICollectionViewDelegate and the collectionView(...didSelectItemAt:...) function to the class HomeViewController directly:

```
class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("item at \(indexPath.section)/\(indexPath.item) tapped")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you might have placed some UIButton in the cell. Tap on some empty area in the cell then you will get the 'Got click on index'